# Can I deny HTTP Requests on a simple socket server?

Tags: java, sockets, http

It's very annoying when you are making a simple socket server and you get an http request. Very anoying if your server doesn't support http requests. Is there a way to detect and deny http requests (from webbrowsers) and only accept tcp/socket connections?

Comment: It's absolutely possible and if you look into the http request specification it's just a matter of looking for http request headers in your code and closing those connections

Comment: @ControlAltDel - that would mean accepting the connection and reading enough of it to understand its http. not sure thats what the OP intends

Comment: @radai Ya I am aware. We are basically saying the same thing

Answer (score 1):

no, because you dont know the payload a client intends to send over a socket until youve accepted the connection and read enough of it to understand its talking HTTP.

In my opinion you should think of the frustration clients are experiencing, and do 2 things:

1. Why are browsers being directed to your (obviously not http) service? can you stop it?
2. Assuming the answer to #1 above is no, maybe implement some simple detection for http requests and respond with a hardcoded http response that renders as a readable error on the browser who sent it? (yes, even though your service isnt http) - a simple detection would be take your input buffer, decode as a us-ascii string, and if it starts with one of the 9 HTTP request methods send out some hardcoded http error response. i suggest error code 402 - payment required :-)